# Appium - Getting a java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.proxy2.$Proxy9.proxyClassLookup() at PageFactory

Tags: automation, appium, pom.xml, appium-android, page-factory

I am getting this exception on running an Appium test. The test fails at PageFactory with the exception below.

```
My POM:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0`
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.telepathy.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>twitter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

- This was working fine up until yesterday, my machine got restarted and this error started coming.
- Already tried with latest version of Appium (7.5.1)
- Did mvn clean and refresh, update

Fails here:
PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(this.driver), this);

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
    jdk.proxy2.$Proxy9.proxyClassLookup()
    at  ​io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.builder.AppiumByBuilder.prepareAnnotationMethods(
ApiumByBuilder.java:84)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the version of Java you are using.  I downgraded from JDK v16 to v15.0.2 and that fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes, this had worked for me as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Aaron Just curious, how did you figure that out?

Answer (score 3):

I also faced same issue but was not getting any solution for it.
Just check you are using AppiumDriver instead of AndroidDriver.
& You are using @FindBy annotation instead of @AndroidFindBy in your page object class.
Also use `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);` instead of `PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);`
This worked for me. It it works for you kindly acknowledge here.
Thanks

Comment: This approach works for me mate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rebuild your project on java version `1.8` (which will be the minimum version), then you will have to insert your `jre` and `jdk` for version `15` or less and it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error but when I am running locally via eclipse it was working fine but when I am running via command line it was failing then I have added compile version in build i.e. gradle in my case. Similarly you can add in maven also it will solve the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue got resolved by following below steps--

1. **Check the versions of maven dependencies -**
   java version - 1.8,
   Appium-java-client: 7.6.0,
   selenium-java: 3.141.59,
   Testng: 7.5
2. Update **JDK compliance level** to JavaSE 11 <= JavaSE15 (Click on project > Windows > Preference > click on Java compiler (left panel) > Click on the dropdown to change JavaSE16 to JavaSE11 > Apply & close )
3. **Initialize the Pagefactory as below:**

   [image]

Note: Replace all the **AndroidElement** occurences to **MobileElement** like in base class, page & test classes.

If this answer is useful to you, kindly **Upvote**. **:)**