# NoSuchMethodException with PageFactory in Appium

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios, page-factory

While using some code like the following:

```
PageFactory.initElements(AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(3)), this)
```

I receive this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.proxy2.$Proxy9.proxyClassLookup()
```

You can read the complete error log [here](https://hastebin.com/woyetoqimo.http).

I found [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67020698) who had this problem, and the only answer is to use JDK 15 instead of JDK 16. I tried, with JDK 15.0.2 and JDK 1.8, but it doesn't solve the problem for me. In addition I would like to continue using JDK 16.

I'm currently using OpenJDK 16.0.2 and Appium 7.5.1.

Do you know how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried again with JDK 15.0.2, and it works now: unfortunately I don't know exactly why.

The following is the init I used in my class:

```
PageFactory.initElements(AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this)
```

Answer (score 0):

*I fixed this situation by changing from Java SE 17.0.1 to Java SE 11.0.12*
[screenshot from Eclipse IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVOJD.jpg)